# What does "less-than" key "greater-than" mean in terms of keybindings?

Tags: keymap, key-bindings

I'm trying to define a prefix keymap for a minor mode, but I'm getting a result I've not seen yet:

```
`link-grammar-mode' Minor Mode Bindings:
key             binding
---             -------

<C-.>           link-grammar-prefix-map

<C-.> <p>       link-grammar-parse-paragraph
<C-.> <r>       link-grammar-parse-region
<C-.> <s>       link-grammar-parse-sentence
```

Here's how I've defined it:

```
(define-prefix-command 'link-grammar-prefix-map)

(define-key link-grammar-prefix-map [s] 'link-grammar-parse-sentence)
(define-key link-grammar-prefix-map [p] 'link-grammar-parse-paragraph)
(define-key link-grammar-prefix-map [r] 'link-grammar-parse-region)

(define-minor-mode link-grammar-mode
  "Enables display of the parse of the natural language text
produced by link-grammar parser library"
  :initial-value nil
  :lighter " LG"
  :keymap '(([C-.] . link-grammar-prefix-map))
  :group 'link-grammar
  (run-hooks link-grammar-hooks)
  (message "link-grammar minor mode activated"))
```

Could please anyone explain what happened? I can see the map added to `minor-mode-map-alist`, but the keys aren't "activated".

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node [`Key Sequences`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Key-Sequences), for possible values of the `KEY` argument to `define-key`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some events understood by Emacs are characters which in turn are just integers. So a key which is an integer can be greater or smaller than another such key.

Then there are events which are represented using symbols, e.g. `return`. Functions that take events as arguments accept different representations for these events. For `return` one can use `"<return>"` or `[return]`. However the vector representation is *only* intended for "symbol events", you can not use it for character events. So `[s]` is wrong, there is no such event; instead use `[?s]` or `"s"`.

Comment: *`[s]` is wrong, there is no such event; instead use `"s"`.* You can also use `[?s]`.

Comment: Thank you! But could you please also comment on this: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html ? Specifically, `[C-backspace]`? Is this also an event? How do you tell, which is a key and which is an event? How do you know what events are available?

Comment: Here you go [Input Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Input-Events). The short answer is use the `kbd` function to conveniently define keys.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that page too, so most of my questions are answered except for `[C-backspace]` (notice how there isn't a backslash before `C` - is this perhaps an error in documentation?).

Comment: An easy way to find out how emacs sees a key is to use `C-h k` mapped to `describe-key`. `C-h k C-backspace` gives me `<C-backspace>` so emacs will definitely recognize this angled braces form. Use this with the `kbd` function.